# tensorflow image retraining with serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to serve retrained inception graph using tensorflow serving. For retraining, I am using this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/image_retraining/). However I need to make changes to this graph to get it working with [serving export code](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_saved_model.py).

Since in tensorflow serving, you will receive serialized images as input, graph input should start with this:

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
feature_configs = {
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
jpegs = tf_example['image/encoded']
images = tf.map_fn(preprocess_image, jpegs, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This images tensor should be input to retrained inception graph. However I don't know if its possible to prepend one graph to another in tensorflow like you can append easily using placeholder_with_input (which has been done in retraining code).

```
graph, bottleneck_tensor, jpeg_data_tensor, resized_image_tensor = (
  create_inception_graph())
```

Ideally, in image retraining code, I receive a placeholder tensor `jpeg_input_data`. I need to append tensor `images` to this placeholder tensor `jpeg_data_tensor` and export it as single graph using exporter so that it can be served using tensorflow serving. However I don't any tensorflow instruction that does it. Are there any other alternatives apart from this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of going about it is:

```
model_path = 'trained/export.pb' 
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:       
        with gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            # Your prepending ops here
            images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
            ...
            images = tf.map_fn(preprocess_image, jpegs, dtype=tf.float32)
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='inception', input_map={'ResizeBilinear:0': images})
```

Notice especially the `input_map` argument. `ResizeBilinear:0` is likely not the correct name of the operation you need - you can list the ops by:

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

I realize this is not a full answer and perhaps not the most efficient but hopefully it can get you started. Just a heads-up, there is also [this blogpost](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow).

Answer (score 0):

So since you have already retrained the model, I'm assuming that the model is a Protobuf, but you can just load that up into a Python object and serve off of that object using a custom function that processes either a batch or an atomic operation.

And to your graph question, as far as I know, when you load a tf.Graph() object you are only working with that object and can't work with other graphs... that being said if you had another graph that is an extension of the existing Inception-V3 Graph then you can easily add that to the computation graph for your custom graph quite easily.